# qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "windows" in ""

Tags: ros2, turtlesim, windows, qt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS 2 tutorial, Introducing turtlesim and rqt, instructs us to execute the following commands in two cmd windows (I am exercising on Windows 10 platform), `ros2 run turtlesim turtlesim_node` and `ros2 run turtlesim turtle_teleop_key`. Both commands fails with the error message:

```
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "windows" in ""
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
```

Does this mean that I need to install Qt? If yes, why isn't Qt included in Foxy release, or, as part of install instruction? Could you provide the pointer where I can download free version of Qt? Once I install Qt, what  else do I need to do so that the turtlesim will work successfully? Thanks a lot for the help.

My foxy installation was successful. At the end of the installation, both `ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker` and `ros2 run demo_nodes_py listener` worked. I am just started with the ros2 tutorial. The command `set | findstr ROS` produced the following:

```
ROS_DISTRO=foxy
ROS_LOCALHOST_ONLY=0
ROS_PYTHON_VERSION=3
ROS_VERSION=2
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/354707/qt.qpa.plugin:-could-not-find-the-qt-platform-plugin-%22windows%22-in-%22%22/) by [Sofia.Mabrey](https://answers.ros.org/users/55730/sofia.mabrey/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2020-06-11

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dawson](https://answers.ros.org/users/55621/dawson/) on 2020-06-13**:
I have the same issue I would like help getting this going. I also cant run rqt without getting plugin.xml non found errors

**Comment by [lzsyvj](https://answers.ros.org/users/55875/lzsyvj/) on 2020-06-18**:
I have the exact same issue.

**Comment by [lzsyvj](https://answers.ros.org/users/55875/lzsyvj/) on 2020-06-18**:
Found a fix:
In Windows 10 set environment variable QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH and point it to where PyQT5 DLL's were installed to, in my case
C:\Python38\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\platforms

**Comment by [Dawson](https://answers.ros.org/users/55621/dawson/) on 2020-06-18**:
I will try this tomorrow and see if it works for me too, thank you so much for sharing your fix!!

**Comment by [Dawson](https://answers.ros.org/users/55621/dawson/) on 2020-06-19**:
I mentioned your fix to the Microsoft team and it fixed the same issue on eloquent as well! thank you Izsyvj

**Comment by [Sofia.Mabrey](https://answers.ros.org/users/55730/sofia.mabrey/) on 2020-06-21**:
It works for me too. Many thanks!

**Comment by [Tortelenny](https://answers.ros.org/users/56272/tortelenny/) on 2020-06-30**:
Same here! Thank you so much!!

**Comment by [staticoli](https://answers.ros.org/users/66061/staticoli/) on 2020-12-21**:
This hasn't helped me, Can someone please help? Also I noticed that is says turtlesim is only available for Dashing onward? I'm using Foxy, is this going to hinder my ability to use turtlesim?

**Comment by [Hshahzad108277](https://answers.ros.org/users/66503/hshahzad108277/) on 2020-12-25**:
Same here with staticoli, this fix doesnt work for me and seems to be the only fix on the internet. If anyone has a new fix please share it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I run into the same problem. In my case (Foxy on Windows 10), the solution was to set the variable QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH to C:\dev\ros2_foxy\bin\platforms,  the path to qwindows.dll delivered by ROS2. It was confusing since there is another qwindows.dll file under C:\Python38\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\platforms as described by @Izsyvj.

---

Originally posted by [flargo](https://answers.ros.org/users/66629/flargo/) with karma: 106 on 2020-12-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [prabin_rath](https://answers.ros.org/users/50841/prabin_rath/) on 2021-01-01**:
This worked like a charm. Thank You :) I also set that up in the Power Shell profile settings such that I don't have to do it every time I open a new shell.

**Comment by [sabin](https://answers.ros.org/users/69139/sabin/) on 2021-02-01**:
Worked for me as well. Wish the ROS team would add this in their tutorial.

**Comment by [Erfan Zekri](https://answers.ros.org/users/54014/erfan-zekri/) on 2021-03-22**:
I tried it and it works for me too. Thank you!
It's really necessary to add this solution in ROS2 tutorial

**Comment by [Dorthyn](https://answers.ros.org/users/73262/dorthyn/) on 2021-04-13**:
It also worked for me!(rolling version on Windows 10). Just like what you said, it is weird that a qwindows.dll is also in PyQt5\Qt\plugins\platforms

**Comment by [0zzy0sbourne](https://answers.ros.org/users/96789/0zzy0sbourne/) on 2022-02-13**:
I don't have \PyQt5 folder inside the \Lib\site-packages. Should i install PyQt5 with pip?

**Comment by [ROS2_user](https://answers.ros.org/users/106128/ros2_user/) on 2022-05-26**:
This also worked for me!